# To apply mutate with an other line

Tags: r, dplyr, mutated

I have a table and I would like to add a column that calculates the percentage compared to the previous line.
You have to do as calculation takes the line 1 divided by line 2 and on the line 2, you indicate the result

Example

```
month <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
sell <-c(258356,278958,287928,312254,316287,318999)
df <- data.frame(month, sell)

df %>% mutate(augmentation = sell[month]/sell[month+1])
```

```
  month   sell  resultat
1    10 258356        NA
2    11 278958 0.9261466
3    12 287928 0.9688464
4    13 312254 0.9220955
5    14 316287 0.9872489
6    15 318999 0.9914984
```

Comment: You need the `lag` and `lead` functions

Answer (score 0):

#### dplyr

You can just use `lag` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(resultat = lag(sell)/sell)
```

Output:

```
  month   sell  resultat
1    10 258356        NA
2    11 278958 0.9261466
3    12 287928 0.9688464
4    13 312254 0.9220955
5    14 316287 0.9872489
6    15 318999 0.9914984
```

#### data.table

Another option is using `shift`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, resultat:= shift(sell)/sell][]
```

Output:

```
   month   sell  resultat
1:    10 258356        NA
2:    11 278958 0.9261466
3:    12 287928 0.9688464
4:    13 312254 0.9220955
5:    14 316287 0.9872489
6:    15 318999 0.9914984
```